# GitHub workflow event of file creation and update issue

Tags: github-actions

I need to trigger GitHub workflow for file create and update events in same repo as workflow and in different repo as well (multiple repositories). I have written following code/yaml for the same, but workflow is not getting triggered as expected. What might be the issue with yaml?

```
name: wf_trial

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - 'Content-repo/Backup/**.zip'
      - 'FirstRepo/**.txt'

jobs:
  SCR:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: "!contains(github.event.commits[0].message, 'Daily Repo Sync')"
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: workflow triggered
        run: echo "Workflow is Triggered."
        shell: bash
```

I have checked and verified correctness of repositories and paths.

Comment: Are you perhaps triggering this from another workflow? If so, you need to [use a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#triggering-a-workflow-from-a-workflow).

Comment: I am not triggering this from another workflow. Zip file is being created or updated in repository by some other means and I need to trigger this workflow by sensing the create or update of zip.

Comment: What other means? Do you see an error? Is the job just skipped? Is the workflow not triggered at all? Is the repo public, can you link to a workflow run?

Comment: I am creating/updating files by using API. I don't see any error, but workflow is not getting triggered at all. Repo is not public.
One observation - If I remove 'paths' from trigger section, it is working on push. That means something wrong with path. However, I have verified the path including spelling. 
Note: FirstRepo and Content-repo are the names of repositories and workflow yaml is stored at location 'FirstRepo/.github/workflows
/SCR.yaml'

Comment: How do you use the API? From your machine? From some other automation?

Comment: The workflow would only ever trigger for changes in the same repo that it is in. The path never includes the name of the repository, it's relative to the root directory of the repo. It looks like you're trying to trigger off a change in a different repository, and include the name of the repository itself in the path.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminW. It is working with your solution..